# Swift Design: why array.endIndex is large than real lastest index and CGRect.maxY is same

Tags: arrays, swift, cgrect

In the process of programming in swift, I encountered such a problem which confused me.

[image]

as shown in the picture above。

I found that the maxY property of CGRect is actually not included in CGRect. Because for a CGRect whose origin coordinate is (0, 0) and the length and width are 100, its actual maxY should be (0, 99).

I also found that the same problem exists in Array, for example, an array of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], his subscript should be 0-5, but the endIndex property of Array is 6.

I wonder why it is designed this way, does it make any sense?

Comment: Is this a question about CGRect or Array, quite different topics imo. Anyway for Array it’s s clearly stated in the documentation that endIndex is one past the last index.

Answer (score 0):

**Senario 1**

`CGRect.contains(_:)` return true only if the coordinate is inside the rectangle or it is on the `minimumX` & `minimumY` edges.

If the point lies on the maximum edges it will return `false`.

In your case you are trying to check a point which lies on the maximum edge of the rect. So it will return ```false``.

[Check the Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains)

> A point is considered inside the rectangle if its coordinates lie inside the rectangle or on the minimum X or minimum Y edge.

**Senario 2**

[endIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1539310-endindex) of an array is defined as follows.

> The array’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.

So in your array,

`5` is the last valid element which has the index of `5`. So `endIndex` is defined as the 1 value higher than the index of the last element. So it will return `6`.

Answer (score 0):

`CGRect.contains` is actually refers `CGRectContainsPoint` . As the documentation says

> A point is considered inside the rectangle if its coordinates lie inside the rectangle or on the minimum X or minimum Y edge.

So why?. Lets think we have a frame like `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3, height: 3)`

What we expect that , We want a frame that x position is 0 and width must be 3.

From 0 to 3 Its like :

```
0->1->2->3
```

> Numbers are point , arrows like feet

The distance is `3`  yes but `there is 4 points` thats why Apple wants to eliminate 1 point. We can say that this is the last point from documentation. Thats why `print(rect.contains(.init(x: 0, y: 0)))` is true and `print(rect.contains(.init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)))` or any other end point is not true